# Полноэкранный режим

Tags: android-sdk, android, java

Запускаю приложение на андроиде 3.0 (Motorola Xoom). Проблема в том, что оно отображается очень маленьким. Остальная часть дисплея черная. При этом в окне приложения появляется скролл. На предыдущем андроиде все было хорошо. Что указать в коде, чтоб мое приложение занимало весь экран? Может, надо что-то в настройках системы указать?

Код:

```
public class WebUIProto extends Activity {
WebView page;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
    // Setup browser        
       setContentView(R.layout.main);       
       page = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.WebView);
       WebSettings webSettings = page.getSettings();
       webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
       webSettings.setSupportZoom(false);
       webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true); 
       webSettings.setGeolocationEnabled(true);
       webSettings.setSupportMultipleWindows(false);
       webSettings.setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
       webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

       page.loadUrl("http://hashcode.ru/");
    }
}
```

В R.layout.main ничего не менял.

Comment: А ваш main layout как-то глянуть можно?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте в манифесте написать

```
<supports-screens android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:anyDensity="true" />
 <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4" android:targetSdkVersion="8"/>
```

Если не заработает покажите файл разметки

Comment: Очень помогло.